# I am having some trouble with adding checkbox column in a my datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a datagridview on my page, the datasource of which keeps changing based on records retrieved with pair of values from 2 combo-boxes,
I need to add a checkbox column to my datagrid, which has no databinding with any column from my database table, i am using this code

```
public void RefreshDataGrid(string query)
        {
            Buisness_logic bl = new Buisness_logic();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bl.GetDataTable(query);
            SetUpDataGridView();
            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
        }

        public void SetUpDataGridView()
        {

            DataGridViewCellStyle style = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle;
            style.BackColor = Color.White;
            style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Sr.No";
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Rate";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 70;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Amount";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 100;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Mode";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 60;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Support";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 80;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Team1";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 100;
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Team2";
            dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 100;
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].HeaderText = "Team3";
            dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width = 100;
                DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column3 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                column3.Name = "Column3";
                column3.HeaderText = "IsCheck";
                column3.ReadOnly = false;
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column3);
        }
```

It datagridview is good when tge form loads the first time, but when i change the value of the combo-boxes and the datasource changes, the columns get messed up, and a no. of checkbox columns get added and that ruins my form,

here is the code i used to retrieve the records from table

```
Combo_pair pr1 = combo_match_code.SelectedItem as Combo_pair;
                int match_code_f1 = Convert.ToInt32(pr1.Text);
                Combo_pair pair = combo_name.SelectedItem as Combo_pair;
                int userid_f1 = Convert.ToInt32(pair.Value);
                string query = "Select int_sr_no,double_rate,double_amount,txt_mode,txt_support,double_team1,double_team2,double_team3 from match_transaction where int_match_code='" + match_code_f1 + "' AND int_user_id='" + userid_f1 + "' AND is_deleted=0";
                RefreshDataGrid(query);
```

this is the image when the form loads for the first time

[image]

and this is the image after i change the combo box values a few times

[image]

*(sorry, having trouble with images)
i really need some help with these, thanxx

Comment: You are calling `SetUpDataGridView` for every combobox change ? since you add a checkbox column there it would go on adding as many a times its called.

Comment: so i should set a counter so that it executes only the first time??? any help how the counter must look like?? sorry kinda new with datagrids :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the answer I'm just going to restate the problem in steps (so that my solution hopefully makes more sense):

- You have a databound DataGridView where you want to change details of columns
- When you want refresh the data in the grid (your search criteria change) your changes to the columns are overwritten
- To fix this you update date grid datasource and remake all the changes
- This has the side effect that an unbound checkbox column you add is being added multiple times

So the problem in a nutshell is **how to keep the changes to columns while also only having the one column**?

The trick here is the DataGridView's AutoGenerateColumns property.

For sake of argument let is say that you first setup your grid during the form load - if not then you might need a boolean field to store if you have previously setup the grid.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // So this is the first time we call your refresh grid with some default string query
    RefreshDataGrid(query);

    // Now one time only we call SetUpDataGridView()
    SetUpDataGridView();

    // Now once we have done that we set AutoGenerateColumns to false
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

}

public void RefreshDataGrid(string query)
{
    Buisness_logic bl = new Buisness_logic();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bl.GetDataTable(query);
    // We no longer need to call SetUpDataGridView()
    // SetUpDataGridView();
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
}
```

Your SetUpDataGridView() method is pretty much identical:

```
public void SetUpDataGridView()
{

    DataGridViewCellStyle style = dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle;
    style.BackColor = Color.White;
    style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Sr.No";
    dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;

    // And so on for all the columns...

    dataGridView1.Columns[7].Width = 100;
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column3 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
    column3.Name = "Column3";
    column3.HeaderText = "IsCheck";
    column3.ReadOnly = false;
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column3);
}
```

So now when the combboxes containing the query information change you can call RefreshDataGrid() but it will only update the data, not change your custom settings.

---

One suggestion for the RefreshDataGrid() method is to add a line like so:

```
public void RefreshDataGrid(string query)
{
    Buisness_logic bl = new Buisness_logic();
    // This is the new line
    dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(List<>);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bl.GetDataTable(query);
    // We no longer need to call SetUpDataGridView()
    // SetUpDataGridView();
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
}
```

This can reduce flicker as column widths change and also is often necessary to make changing the DataSource show at all.

Comment: Wow....that was so awesome that although I had already solved my problem, i re coded my whole form again, this solution looks clean......geez thanxx a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the gridview only once.

A good place to do this is after `InitializeComponent()`.

Since this is a fixed column, you could also add it through the designer (Edit Columns).
That way the code would get add to `InitializeComponent()`.

`InitializeComponent()` is usually called in the constructor of your form.

At present you are adding this line

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column3);
```

Will cause the checkbox column to be added several times.

Comment: you could try to clear the columns before recreating them dataGridView1.Columns.Clear

Comment: but i am changing the datasource frequently(i.e a datatable filled with records after i fire query each time someone changes the combobox value), so won't it get ruined if i don't call the setupdatagridview method evry time i change the datasource???

Comment: ok, i tried to clear the columns as u said, but it gives exception on the very next line :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: Clear would clear off all the columns, so stuff like `dataGridView1.Columns[0] ...` would fail

Comment: C'mon guys, help me with some other way round to this : dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column3);

Comment: No. Changing the datasource shouldn't affect it. Generated columns should still work fine.